# Edit / delete custom post types through web page (not admin)

Tags: custom-post-types

I want it to be possible for the users to edit and delete their own posts, not only through the admin panel as it is by default. I've look around on the net but haven't found any information about it.

How can this be done?

Comment: To answer your question we have to write whole article and implement almost everything for you. Such questions are not welcome here. Try to ask narrow question.

Comment: @EugeneManuilov: Dear Eugene. If you look at the answer below you see that's not the case. This can be done by just change the user role, which I was hoping and you don't need to write "whole article". This question as well as the answer below can definitely be of help for other users in the future, and what I wrote in my question was narrow enough to answer the question in a good way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-end-editor/

If you assign users the Contributor role, they'll be able edit their own posts from the frontend. You could use a basic redirect to prevent Contributors from being shown the admin panel on login... look around StackExchange/Google for several solutions to this.

For another solution, which will give you more control over the process (including adding/editing/deleting posts), check out the tutorial at http://wp.tutsplus.com/series/posting-via-the-front-end/